# Python re to parse a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse a file that contains multiple blocks. The file looks as below.

```
$ Start of something1
.........contents
.........
$ End of something1
$ Start of something2
..........
..........
$ End of something2
some comments that should be included in block2.
$ Start of something3
.......
.......
$ End of something3
```

I have succeeded to parse from the first line ($ Start) to the last line of a block that contains "$ End of .....".
But the problem I had was basically for the blocks like 2nd in my sample where it has some comments after the ending footer. 
I basically need to find $ Start at the beggining and find the next $ Start but grep everything before the next "$ Start".
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have sample code? Do you use nested `for` loops? Instead of making `$ End` the end condition, just make the next `$ Start` the end condition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead that is not part of the capturegroup:

```
t = """$ Start of something1
.........contents
.........
$ End of something1
$ Start of something2
..........
..........
$ End of something2
some comments that should be included in block2.
$ Start of something3
.......
.......
$ End of something3""" 


import re

for k in re.findall(r'(\$ Start of .*?)(?=(?:\$ Start|\Z))',t,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE):
        print "------ new find --------" 
        print k  
        print "------- end ------------\n\n"
```

Output:

```
------ new find --------
$ Start of something1
.........contents
.........
$ End of something1

------- end ------------


------ new find --------
$ Start of something2
..........
..........
$ End of something2
some comments that should be included in block2.

------- end ------------


------ new find --------
$ Start of something3
.......
.......
$ End of something3
------- end ------------
```

**Explanation:**

The pattern captures a group starting with literal `$ Start of` followed by as few as possible characters (including newlines due to re.DOTALL) so that the match is followed by either `$ Start` or `\Z` == end of string.

The (?=..) is a positive lookahead, its content (?:\$ Start|\Z) is not part  of the group before it and its own group is non.capturing.

- 1st Capturing Group `(\$ Start of .*?)`

  - `\$` matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
  - `Start of` matches the characters  `Start of` literally (case sensitive)
  - `.*?` matches any character

    - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- Positive Lookahead `(?=(\$ Start|\Z))`

  - Assert that the Regex below matches
  - 2nd Capturing Group `(\$ Start|\Z)`

    - 1st Alternative `\$ Start`

      - `\$` matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
      - `Start` matches the characters  `Start` literally (case sensitive)
    - 2nd Alternative `\Z`

      - `\Z` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Global pattern flags

- `re.MULTILINE` : multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of
  each line (not only begin/end of string)   re.
- `re.DOTALL`: single line. Dot matches newline characters

You can view the explanation at https://regex101.com/r/h27O0d/1 where I developed the regex based on your text.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Would have been nice to know where my answer was not helpful, so I can improve upon it. #